# unable to update logitech unifying receiver

Tags: fedora, upgrade, firmware

An update for logitech unifying receiver constantly pop-ups but when I tried to update it will just fail.

I also tried this

```
sudo fwupdmgr refresh && fwupdmgr update
```

But I will just got this

```
Fetching metadata https://s3.amazonaws.com/lvfsbucket/downloads/firmware.xml.gz
Downloading…           [****************************************]
Fetching signature https://s3.amazonaws.com/lvfsbucket/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.asc
Downloading…           [****************************************]
Downloading RQR12.07_B0029 for Unifying Receiver...
Updating RQR12.07_B0029 on Unifying Receiver...
Writing…               failed to erase fw @0x00: failed to send data: Device 046d:aaaa has not been opened
```

Then I need to re-plugin it again for it to work.

ref: https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2017/05/22/updating-logitech-hardware-on-linux/

Comment: You presumably need root for both operations, so `sudo fwupdmgr update`.

Comment: @meuh I tried both command on sudo but got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had that problem in Fedora 26. Today they released an update that should solve the issue.
Update the packages and repeat the procedure you have done before:

```
sudo fwupdmgr refresh 
sudo fwupdmgr update
```